# How to print invalid QTime?

Tags: qt

I want to do something like this

```
QTime time (25,0,0);
qDebug() << time.toString();
```

But that will be invalid QTime and outputs ""

Can it be done in some way other then converting QTime to seconds, seconds to string?

Comment: which output are you expecting ?

Comment: The way you call constructor is just invalid. But you still can create QTime(0,0,0).addSecs(25*60*60). QTime works exactly like clocks, so your time will be "01:00:00" (and will be the same as QTime(1,0,0)). I have never seen any data structure (other than just int) that represents time interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTime is time of day, and thus 25:0:0 is invalid. What you seem to want is not time-of-day, but a duration. Qt doesn't ship a QDuration class. It's quite simple though to roll your own (durations are much simpler than dates and times, no timezones etc.).